# How to select a View(FlatList) in detox test code which is behind another View(Button on View) but visible?

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, ios-simulator, detox

On single screen there is a `FlatList` which is scrollable. After scrolling I perform `tap()` action and a `View` is appears which is next button. Then again scroll the list. But second scroll is not working via code.

```
await element(by.id('player_list_scroll')).scroll(100, 'down');
await element(by.text('Player1')).tap();
// Here Next button appears above list but still list is visible and scrollable in device and thats functionality.
await element(by.id('player_list_scroll')).scroll(200, 'down');
```

on simulator I can see the second scroll action and test ends without failing. But on Simulator I don't see List getting scrolled second time.

Comment: **on simulator I can see the second scroll action and test ends without failing**. I am confused now, did you mean to say emulator and simulator ??

Comment: Test written to scroll passes but scroll action do not happen on simulator(iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Try using swipe in the simulator instead of scroll, it would most likely work.
Ex: await element(by.id(testid)).swipe(up, slow, 0.5);